# How to discard alert summary when alert status is RESOLVED in Prometheus Alertmanager?

Tags: prometheus, go-templates, prometheus-alertmanager

Consider a simple alert:

```
      - alert: SomeAlert
      expr: SomeExpression > SomeValue
      labels:
        severity: notification
        slack: SomeSlackChannel
      annotations:
        summary: "This alert was fired!"
```

Now I want to show the `summary` only when the status of the alert is FIRING. In case of RESOLVED status, I would like to discard the alert summary from slack notification.

How to selectively show/hide alert summary depending on the status of the alert?

I tried the following:

```
      - alert: SomeAlert
      expr: SomeExpression > SomeValue
      labels:
        severity: notification
        slack: SomeSlackChannel
      {{ if eq .Status "firing }}
      annotations:
        summary: "This alert was fired!"
      {{ end }}
```

but didn't work. It seems like `.Status` is not accessible to conditionally show/hide alert summary.

Comment: What do you mean by "hide the alert summart" what do you like to achieve by that?

Comment: I wish to show the RESOLVED alert without any details that I get to see in FIRING types of alerts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this on Alertmanager template's level.

1. Configure your template. Be it HTML for email, or just text for Slack, etc.

`{{ define "simply.resolved" }}The alert is resolved.{{ end}}`

2. Configure alertmanager receiver to use this template.

```yaml
  name: my_receiver
  slack_configs:
  - send_resolved: true
    text: '{{ template "simply.resolved" . }}'
```

More info: https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/notification_examples/